# Automated Facebook friend requests

Tags: facebook, facebook-privacy, friends, facebook-friend-request

My father has a Facebook account he barely uses, which I can't even find on google or Facebook. He changed his privacy settings a few days ago. Before everyone could send a friend request, now only friends of friends can send ones. He has no friends on Facebook.

Since the change of his settings, he gets numerous friend requests from people he doesn't even know, all girls in my age (I'm also female 17). One of the girls is from my class and I asked her. She stated that she never sent any request to him nor to any other person. I am not friends with my dad on facebook.

**Why does he get automated friend requests and why only from young girls?**

Note: Today I tried to help him and we changed his settings again that everyone can send friend requests. My theory is, that since he doesn't has any friends on facebook with the change of his settings he couldn't get any friend requests and facebook doesn't want that. But I'm not sure if that is the truth.

Comment: Just a guess - is it possible those are scams accounts? This girl from your class - does the same profile that request friendship from your father is the one you're friend with on your Facebook? The most popular scams accounts are of young (pretty) girls. Also, does the girl from your class can see she sent a friend request to your father? If not, it's also a hint for scam.

Comment: He has 0 friends, or just almost none?

Comment: @arieljannai 0 friends

Comment: @arieljannai He clicked on my classmates profile and saw me and other classmates as her friends there, would a fake profile also have the same friends? I would know

Comment: OK, so it's probably not a scam. No idea right now ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: It is possible that your father's name was appeared to other people's You May Know section based on location and interest and they would have sent the friend request.

Comment: @serenesat But the girl he got the friend request from, didn't send the friend request.

Comment: did you check both have same user ID? The request might have send as spam.